# Android NDK - which android architectures to include in Application.mk?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I recently started playing with the NDK, hoping to convert my lib into Android. My problem is the number of binaries *per-architecture* than are produced after a successful *ndk-build*
My NDK version is the *r10c* and building a simple application (executable) like the following:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main() {
   printf("hello from Windows Mr. Android!!");
   return 0;
}
```

creates **7** architecture folders for the binaries in */libs* folders, which are:

- arm64-v8a
- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- mips
- mips64
- x86
- x86_64

The binaries averages from 6 to 10 KB but all together are puts about 64KB (disk size).

My problem is that i developed a cross-platform engine *(Windows, Linux and OSX)* and with the static linking i get a size of about *2.5MB* on *each* platform supported. I don't know about the Android binary format (ELF?) but i'm going to assume it will end with about the ~same size.

That means if i succeed to convert my library into Android i will end up with about *(7 * 2.5) = 17.5 MBs* of binaries, covering all architectures.

It's really necessary to build for all architectures with `APP_ABI := all` and just forget about? Does the Android *chooses* the correct version on execution? Is this the standard way to do building for Android and know that every Android out there will be supported ?

*Bonus question:*

I'm using Android on VirtualBox and connected to a shared folder to my OS but my Android shows the binaries with a question mark and asks me how to open them. Does this requires some kind of *bundling* like on OSX to get properly executed? tx

Comment: you can also build the different apk for each ABI http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: @Selvin, thanx for the link, describes it exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what devices you target most of android mobile phones now days using

```
armeabi-7a
```

If your intention is to run your application on Genymotion like emulator too then add x86 binary.

So all libs are not requires just include the according to devices you want to support

so you can specify in Application.mk like below if want to target most of android mobile phones.

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a,x86
```

Comment: so samsung galaxy 3 is genymotion (<= I'm just laughing from your ignorance) ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_3_10.1 there are plenty real devices with x86 architecture ...

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Well, my problem is that i don't have any targets. I'm just looking to support Android in general. So i'm going to follow the `armeabi-v7a,x86` for a start :) Just because im total noob in Android, how exactly this works? I'm going to create one APK with all architecture binaries or several ?

Comment: my intention is not to say genymotion is only x86 but majority android devices are arm based so you can always look for CPU Specs of device to include libs to support for it according to need.so I guess armeabi-v7a and x86 seems enough to me.Samsung Galaxy Tab 3's CPU is x86.